# how to use Colon as the name of file when saving dataframes in pandas on Windows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to save my file but i cant put `:` as part of the name like "14:00" i want the name to be the time it was created

```
name = str(datetime.datetime.now())
df.to_csv(f"{name}.csv")
```

how can i do that?

Comment: I don't think colons are legal on windows.

Comment: it dose not work somehow it stops when it gets to :

Comment: That's what happens on windows.

Comment: yes thats it you cant put : as the name of your file in windows

Answer (score 1):

You could use `formating`

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

now = datetime.now()

...
df.to_csv(f'{now: %Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss}.csv')

# 2021-04-17_19h50m18s.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot because `:` is [a reserved character for paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) in Windows (which comments in OP suggest you are using):

```
Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode 
characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the
following:

The following reserved characters:
    < (less than)
    > (greater than)
    : (colon)
    " (double quote)
    / (forward slash)
    \ (backslash)
    | (vertical bar or pipe)
    ? (question mark)
    * (asterisk)
```

Use something else, traditionally people use an underscore: `_`.